# Responding to Growl notifications with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, growl

I'm looking to write some Applescript which is run in response to Growl events.

e.g. email arrives from a given user which effects some change on my Nabaztag.

I can find plenty on the internet about creating and displaying Growl notifications with Applescript, but not listening for Growl notifications.

I don't have to use Applescript, but it seemed a nice thing to look at. The applications I'm looking at may or may not have Applescript dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, one option might be to use a display style in growl that would give you something to script off of.

So for notifications you want to have fire scripts just choose "MailMe" as the display style and then set up rules in mail.app that would let you respond to certain alerts coming from growl by firing off their related scripts.

Comment: My actual use case was using Spotify and the Volume control. Spotify doesn't have any applescript interface, and Volume control has very little scriptability. Thanks.